# Circle and Pentagon Collision Detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I currently have two objects one is a pentagon, and one is a circle. I would like to check if they are touching, and if they are, I'd like them to do something.

I have my circle function where I specify the centre, height and width ( so I can draw an oval if I want)
and my pentagon, I pass in 5 points, and it'll fill it, so its a pentagon

I was originally thinking if I find out the area of these two and somehow do something with it but I can't quite seem to wrap my head around it

Any suggestions ?

Below are how my circles and pentagon are made

```
Polygon(m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY - (m_iDrawHeight*2),
            m_iCurrentScreenX + m_iDrawWidth, m_iCurrentScreenY - (m_iDrawHeight),
            m_iCurrentScreenX + (m_iDrawWidth / 2), m_iCurrentScreenY + (m_iDrawHeight/2),
            m_iCurrentScreenX - (m_iDrawWidth / 2), m_iCurrentScreenY + (m_iDrawHeight/2),
            m_iCurrentScreenX - m_iDrawWidth, m_iCurrentScreenY - (m_iDrawHeight))
```

first set of coord is the top and second and last is the left and right and the middle two is the bottom last two poitns

and

```
Oval(
        m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY,
        m_iCurrentScreenX + m_iDrawWidth - 1,
        m_iCurrentScreenY + m_iDrawHeight - 1)
```

Comment: I recommend discussing the research you have already performed to that answers don't have to retread  old ground.

Comment: Also you should state how exact you want it. A lot of the time you can get away with a pair of circles and completely ignore that the pentagon isn't actually round.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is collision detection between circle and convex.

See, for example: [Collision detection polygon/circle](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/poly-circle.php)

> To test if a circle has collided with a polygon, we can simplify the problem to a series of Line/Circle collisions, one for each side of the polygon.  Also, if needed, test whether the centre of the circle is inside the polygon to cover the case where the circle is enclosed with no lines touching.

Comment: logic + geometry = answer